# ajax success function - check if response contains a string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl

Using PHP cURL to submit data to a remote server and jQuery ajax to do front end routine. All is fine except for the response data, the url I submit to returns some HTML after my flag set by echo in the PHP curl.

So what is returned looks like

```
Submission was successful<!DOCTYPE html>
//bunch of other html
```

My success function is like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    if (result.indexOf("Submission was successful") > -1) {
    //Do stuff
    }
```

Also tried

```
if (data = "Submission was successful") {
//Do stuff
}
```

Which usually works when there is nothing after the "Submission was succesful". How do I get my success function to fire as long as the expected string is present, regardless of what comes after it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried

```
if (data.indexOf("Submission was successful") > -1) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Man I feel stupid. Thanks, no idea why i thought 'result' would work when using (data). Appreciate it mate.

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data.match(/submission was successful/i)) {
        //Do stuff
    }else{
        // failure
    }

}
```